# The import org.apache.jasper cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat

I recently installed Eclipse on a new machine, trying to figure out what I might be missing in terms of versioning or library update with this error.

```
The import org.apache.jasper cannot be resolved
```

Error in code:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core.ForEach"%>
```

Comment: Hm, why would you import `org.apache.jasper.tagplugins.jstl.core.ForEach`? This class is a backend class for the `c:forEach` tag.

Answer (score 0):

just adding the **jasper.jar** from the ***tomcat*** lib folder to the libraries in build path  solved the resolving import issue for me

Comment: Putting it in the WAR file should work too.